# scrollbar not scrollable footer taking up page in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, css, custom-wordpress-pages

Having issues after converting HTML Template to Wordpress Theme. I'm using a social media theme called Adda and the scrolling bar at the bottom that shows the active users is displaying active users stacked on top of each other instead of in a row that you can scroll through. Since the HTML and CSS was premade my guess is the issue is in my functions.php, but I've included the HTML and CSS I think could help. Any help would be appreciated.

[What it should look like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GG6pkYBIV5cuRvni-o18f9x6qaWQYygX/view?usp=sharing)

[What mine looks like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlg_jdMT4YcgfvxpJ0XxeKtQHhDWNyh7/view?usp=sharing)

[What mine looks like in mobile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BygzeaQrg_2MXeBK0wxmdub6_fneiqpN/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a my function.php

```
       <?php

//load stylesheets
function load_stylesheets()
{

    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('bicon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/vendor/bicon.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bicon');

    wp_register_style('flaticon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/vendor/flaticon.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('flaticon');

    wp_register_style('plyr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/plugins/plyr.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('plyr');

    wp_register_style('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/plugins/slick.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('slick');

    wp_register_style('nice', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/plugins/nice-select.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('nice');

    wp_register_style('perfect', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('perfect');

    wp_register_style('lightgallery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/plugins/lightgallery.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('lightgallery');

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');

    wp_register_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');












//load scripts

function addjs()
{

    wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('popper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper');

    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');

    wp_register_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/slick.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('slick');

    wp_register_script('nice', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/nice-select.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('nice');

    wp_register_script('plyr', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/plyr.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('plyr');

    wp_register_script('perfect', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('perfect');

    wp_register_script('lightgallery', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/lightgallery-all.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('lightgallery');

    wp_register_script('imageloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('lightgallery');

    wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/plugins/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope');

    wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/main.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('main');

}
```

Here is the HTML for the scrollbar

```
<div class="frnd-search-inner custom-scroll">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-1.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author">Jon Wilime</h6>
                                                <p>Many desktop publishing</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-2.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Jon Wileyam</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">add friend</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-3.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Mili Raoulin</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">add friend</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-4.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Jon Wilime</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">10 mutual friends</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-5.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Robart faul</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">12 mutual friends</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-3.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Mili Raoulin</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">add friend</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-4.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Jon Wilime</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">10 mutual friends</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center profile-active">
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->
                                            <div class="profile-thumb active">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <figure class="profile-thumb-small">
                                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/images/profile/profile-small-5.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                                                    </figure>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- profile picture end -->

                                            <div class="posted-author">
                                                <h6 class="author"><a href="profile.html">Robart faul</a></h6>
                                                <button class="add-frnd">12 mutual friends</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

CSS for scrollbar

```
/*Custom Scroll (Perfect Scroll)*/
.custom-scroll {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-y,
    .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-x {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

        .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-y [class*="ps__thumb"],
        .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-x [class*="ps__thumb"] {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

    .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-y {
        width: 3px;
        right: 2px;
    }

        .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-y .ps__thumb-y {
            width: 100%;
            right: 0;
        }

    .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-x {
        height: 6px;
        bottom: 3px;
    }

        .custom-scroll.ps .ps__rail-x .ps__thumb-x {
            height: 100%;
        }

.slick-arrow-style button.slick-arrow {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

    .slick-arrow-style button.slick-arrow.slick-next {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }

    .slick-arrow-style button.slick-arrow:hover {
        color: #dc4734;
    }

.slick-track {
    line-height: 1;
}

.slick-row-3 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -3px;
}

    .slick-row-3 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 3px;
    }

.slick-row-4 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -4px;
}

    .slick-row-4 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 4px;
    }

.slick-row-5 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -5px;
}

    .slick-row-5 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 5px;
    }

.slick-row-6 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -6px;
}

    .slick-row-6 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 6px;
    }

.slick-row-7 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -7px;
}

    .slick-row-7 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 7px;
    }

.slick-row-8 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -8px;
}

    .slick-row-8 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 8px;
    }

.slick-row-9 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -9px;
}

    .slick-row-9 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 9px;
    }

.slick-row-10 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -10px;
}

    .slick-row-10 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

.slick-row-11 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -11px;
}

    .slick-row-11 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 11px;
    }

.slick-row-12 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -12px;
}

    .slick-row-12 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 12px;
    }

.slick-row-13 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -13px;
}

    .slick-row-13 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 13px;
    }

.slick-row-14 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -14px;
}

    .slick-row-14 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 14px;
    }

.slick-row-15 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}

    .slick-row-15 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 15px;
    }

.slick-row-16 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -16px;
}

    .slick-row-16 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 16px;
    }

.slick-row-17 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -17px;
}

    .slick-row-17 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 17px;
    }

.slick-row-18 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -18px;
}

    .slick-row-18 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 18px;
    }

.slick-row-19 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -19px;
}

    .slick-row-19 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 19px;
    }

.slick-row-20 .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -20px;
}

    .slick-row-20 .slick-list .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 20px;
    }





/*------- friend search box start -------*/
.friends-search {
    width: 100%;
}

.frnd-search-title {
    height: 62px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #dc4734;
}

    .frnd-search-title .frnd-search-icon,
    .frnd-search-title .close-btn {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

        .frnd-search-title .frnd-search-icon:hover,
        .frnd-search-title .close-btn:hover {
            color: #333333;
        }

    .frnd-search-title p {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 1;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

.search-box {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.search-field {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #666666;
}

.search-btn {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
}

    .search-btn:hover {
        color: #dc4734;
    }

.friend-search-list {
    bottom: calc(100% + 10px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}

    .friend-search-list.show {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }

    .friend-search-list ul li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

        .friend-search-list ul li:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .friend-search-list ul li .add-frnd {
            display: block;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            color: #666666;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

            .friend-search-list ul li .add-frnd:hover {
                color: #dc4734;
            }

.frnd-search-inner {
    height: 350px;
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
}

    .frnd-search-inner ul li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .frnd-search-inner ul li .posted-author p {
            color: #666666;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding-top: 5px;
        }

/*------- friend search box end -------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the css.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

It looks like you are using a bulleted list. Typically the items or

in the list will be stacked on top of each other by default. To get a better understanding see what happens when you remove "display: inline-block;" from the simulation in the link below.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal